# Pry on the production server - how can I make it work there?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debugging, pry

I can debug an app locally with `binding.pry` just fine. But I need to that on the remote server (webiste) as well, because locally I don't have any error but on production I do. So put `binding.pry` in the source file on the server and when I made a post request to the website, I didn't return any response and even when I ran `rails console` on the server didn't change anything and there was no output in `rails console`.

It's a dev server, so it's visible in the internet but it's a developer server, although for rails it's production because `RAIL_ENV` is equal to `production`. I really need to debug it the way I can do locally using pry. How can I do it?

update:

```
# bundle exec pry-remote
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/drb/drb.rb:736:in `rescue in block in open': druby://127.0.0.1:9876 - #<Errno::ECONNREFUSED: Connection refused - connect(2)> (DRb::DRbConnError)
  from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/drb/drb.rb:730:in `block in open'
  from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/drb/drb.rb:729:in `each'
  from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/drb/drb.rb:729:in `open'
  from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/drb/drb.rb:1191:in `initialize'
  from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/drb/drb.rb:1171:in `new'
  from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/drb/drb.rb:1171:in `open'
  from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/drb/drb.rb:1087:in `block in method_missing'
  from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/drb/drb.rb:1105:in `with_friend'
  from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/drb/drb.rb:1086:in `method_missing'
  from /web/my_site.com/releases/201501271120/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/pry-remote-0.1.8/lib/pry-remote.rb:289:in `run'
  from /web/my_site.com/releases/201501271120/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/pry-remote-0.1.8/bin/pry-remote:4:in `<top (required)>'
  from /web/my_site.com/releases/201501271120/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/pry-remote:19:in `load'
  from /web/my_site.com/releases/201501271120/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/pry-remote:19:in `<main>'
```

Comment: The difference probably lies in the application server used. How do you run your app locally in development, and how do you serve it in production?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I assume your production app is run by some kind of daemonized application server, such as Puma or Unicorn.

In this setup, [pry-remote](https://github.com/Mon-Ouie/pry-remote) can help.

1. add it to your Gemfile
2. use `binding.remote_pry` instead of `binding.pry`
3. execute `bundle exec pry-remote` on your server

You'll get a pry shell as soon as the breakpoint has been hit.

Comment: Yes, same thing in this regard. Give it a shot!

Comment: Actually, sometimes is get an error in my update - I can't launch it, sometimes not, I can't understand why that is.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by that?

Comment: Look at my update, that error doesn't occurs always, but sometimes it does. What's the cause I can't figure out.

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/Mon-Ouie/pry-remote/issues/8) are people reporting a similar issue. One possible source is Passenger shutting down unused processes. Try [configuring Passenger](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#_resource_control_and_optimization_options) in a way that idle processes are not shut down.

Comment: Whenever I try running `heroku run bundle exec pry-remote` I get the same error as in the question above. I'm running a Rails 4 app on Puma.

Comment: This works for me, **but**, as soon as I try to do anything in the pry console, it exits.